# Laravel Collection not working

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm trying to convert an array to a collection and to map over it. But I receive an error:

```
ErrorException in Poll.php line 90:
Undefined index: id
```

Code:

```
$options = collect($options);
$options->map(function($option) {
   if($this->options->contains('id', $option['id'])) { //line 90
        Option::create($option);
   }
});
```

When I `dd($options);` it looks like this:

```
Collection {#390
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => array:7 [
      "id" => 17
      "slug" => "asdf-1"
      "name" => "asdf"
      "poll_id" => 6
      "created_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
      "votes" => []
    ]
    1 => array:7 [
      "id" => 18
      "slug" => "asdfkowugiw"
      "name" => "asdfkowugiw"
      "poll_id" => 6
      "created_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
      "votes" => []
    ]
    2 => array:7 [
      "id" => 21
      "slug" => "asdf-1"
      "name" => "asdf"
      "poll_id" => 6
      "created_at" => "2016-11-13 17:48:37"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-13 17:48:37"
      "votes" => []
    ]
    3 => array:7 [
      "id" => 22
      "slug" => "asdfkowugiw"
      "name" => "asdfkowugiw"
      "poll_id" => 6
      "created_at" => "2016-11-13 17:48:37"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-13 17:48:37"
      "votes" => []
    ]
  ]
}
```

So this is a collection so I should be able to do this right?:

```
$options = collect($options);
$options->map(function($option) {
   if($this->options->contains('id', $option->id)) {
        Option::create($option);
   }
});
```

But that fails aswel. What is wrong here?

--EDIT--

```
array:7 [
  "id" => 17
  "slug" => "asdf-1"
  "name" => "asdf"
  "poll_id" => 6
  "created_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
  "updated_at" => "2016-11-13 17:39:01"
  "votes" => []
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access id by using arrow as its object like this:

```
$options = collect($options);
$options->map(function($option) {
   if($this->options->contains('id', $option->id)) { //line 90
        Option::create($option);
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the problem I receive: ```Trying to get property of non-object```

Comment: Try to print whats inside $option?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, it seems to me that if `$option` is an array than `$option['id']` should work, please check whats there in each and every iterated `$option`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Saumya Rastogi, I also suspect that the problem came from `$options` data. Some of the items may have not `id` key. So hopefully with simple checking with `isset()` does the trick (or if you want the Laravel way you can use `array_has()`).

```
$options = collect($options);

$options->map(function ($option) {
    // Make sure that "id" key is exsits.
    if (isset($option['id']) && $this->options->contains('id', $option['id'])) {
        Option::create($option);
    }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. It looks like ```$option['id'];``` is not empty. But it cannot be accessed within ```$this->options->contains('id', $option['id'])```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `$this` context is out of reach in this situation. You may try set pass it explicitely, like this:

```
$options = collect($options);
$opts = $this->options;
$options->map(function($option) use ($opts) {
  if($opts->contains('id', $option->id)) {
    Option::create($option);
  }
});
```